# Sending data to a remote form

Tags: php

Let's say I have a form from a remote area `http://example.com/form.php` which contains:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="age">
  <input type="text" name="sex">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How do I send data to that form, submit it and fetch whatever the result of the form submission is? I found a function in the php site but I  don't know how to use it or if it's the right one to use.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#90411

Comment: You can't send data *TO* a form, except for setting the `value` of each element explicitly.  Do you mean you want to submit the form from php to whatever the form's `action` is?

Comment: yes, fill the necessary inputs, submit, the get whatever the result of the submission is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to POST to that form programmatically?  You can do this easily with cURL.

```
$data['name'] = 'Something';
$data['age'] = 'Something Else';
$data['file'] = "@/somepath/somefile";

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/form.php');
curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_POST', true);
curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS', $data);
```

Comment: is using streams harder than using cURL?

Comment: @user1099531, By far, in my opinion

Comment: what if the file is from a remote location, how would the code look like?

Comment: @user1099531, you're going to want to download this file in advance, but it is possible to download and upload simultaneously.  It depends on how you're accessing this remote location.

Comment: **It depends on how you're accessing this remote location.**